# c#, DirectoryEntry fails to read "labeledUri" from openLDAP

Tags: c#, .net, ldap, openldap

Im using c#, DirectoryEntry (System.DirectoryServices) to read and write a users of objectClass "inetOrgPerson".
This works well, until i want to write the Attributes "labeledURI" or "displayName".
Actually, i can write them once, but the second time it fails. I think that DirectoryEntry has trouble to read them from the Ldap. 
I can provide more Code, but i hope this little example gives an idea.

PseudoCode here:

```
DirectoryEntry deFound = null;
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(a_strLdapServer + "/" + a_strLdapBasePath, m_strLdapUser, m_strLdapPw, AuthenticationTypes.None);  
DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher();
deSearch.SearchRoot = de;
deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=person) (uid=" + a_strUserName + "))";

//deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("labeledURI");


SearchResultCollection results = deSearch.FindAll();
if (results.Count == 1)
{
    deFound = results[0].GetDirectoryEntry();
}

            //WORKS ONCE:
deFound.Properties["labeledURI"].Value = "http://www.google.com";
```

Throwed Exception:
deFound.Properties["labeledURI"].Value  'm_deFound.Properties["labeledURI"]' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'   object

Do you know i'm doing wrong?

Comment: figured out read the the "labeledURI" Value from the SearchResult: 
Byte[] bytes = (Byte[]) results[0].Properties["labeledURI"][0];
string strValue = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Forget about changing ldap:// to LDAP:// or other snake oil.
The problem is hidden in Windows8 (and Server2012 as well).

when you can't access 
deFound.Properties["labeledURI"]
or
deFound.Properties["displayName"]
and you're using windows8., then here is a Hotfix:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2802148